# How to get the data of a BarCodeScanner device?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, barcode-scanner

I am developing software that will be used on Honeywell ScanPal EDA50 Data Collector, I am using Angular 5.2.11 and Ionic 4.16 and phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner 8.0.1.

This Data Collector model got a button on the left side that will activate the scanner and read any barcode that you point it to. I am able to use it and paste the barcode text to an input field as long as the input field is selected.

What I am trying to achieve is:
1) The user activates the scanner and scans a barcode.
2) The data is stored on some variable/clipboard.

The problem I have at the moment is that I don't know how to "watch" or identify that the user activates the barcode scanner.

Since I am unable to identify that, I can't trigger an event which will save the barcode data to a variable.

I could not find any documentation that points me to a solution, and that is what I am looking for: To save the barcode data when the user pressed the barcode button and scanned a barcode.

*Please note I am not triggering the barcodescanner from the View, but directly from the device button.*

Answer (score 0):

after you imported the plugin and declared it in your constructor, you can call the scan function, it will open the camera and as soon a code is scanned you can access the response with async/await
like this:

```
import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';
...
constructor(        
     barcodeScanner: BarcodeScanner
) {
}

async scan() {
     try {
         const scannedDada = await this.barcodeScanner.scan();

         //now the constant "scannedDada" holds the data from the code scanned
         //and you can use it as you want
     } catch (error) {
         console.error('error: ', error);
     }
}
```